# Android: How to divide LinearLayout in two parts of exactly the same size?

Tags: android

I have the following layout:

```
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:background="#FFFFFF"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:weightSum="2">

    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:name="ch.lexs.view.LawList"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1">
    </fragment>

    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:name="ch.lexs.view.ParagraphList"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1">
    </fragment>

</LinearLayout>
```

My intention was to divide the LinearLayout in two parts that are exactly the same size. I thought this can be done by using weight. But the second fragment is way smaller. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try setting the widths of both to "fill_parent".

Answer (score 10):

this code maybe help you

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/mainFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.lmhuan.weatherapp.helper.MainFragment" >
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/detailFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.lmhuan.weatherapp.helper.DetailFragment" >
    </fragment>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

You have the `layout_height` of both fragments set to `"fill_parent"` Maybe try without that?

Answer (score 2):

Try to set android:layout_height="0" if you want that layouts have the same height, or android:layout_width="0" if you want the same width.

Answer (score 2):

You have to concern about `weightSum` attribute of the linear layout. Then the `layout_weight`, `layout_height` and `layout_width` attributes of the inner views. It is all that need to divide layout to any ratio.

If you want to divide layout into two parts of same size you have to set `layout_width` attributes to `0dp` of both layouts and `layout_weight` to `1` inside the main layout. Then set `weightSum` to `2` of the parent layout.

Same concept can be applied to divide layout to any ratio. Set all the inside `layout_weight` values sum up to `weightSum`. Then set `layout_width` or `layout_height` to `0dp` according to the orientation you want to divide. Here is the solution layout for this question.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:weightSum="2">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/mainFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/detailFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </fragment>

</LinearLayout>
```

here is an example to divide LinearLayout to 1, 3, 2 ratio vertically.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="6">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:color/white">

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:background="@android:color/black">
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:background="@android:color/white">
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

fill_parent is deprecated so instaed of this you can use match_parent